# How does the Pocket Salsa (Free) app hide its video files?

Tags: android, internal-storage

I'm looking to accomplish the same thing. Also, is it ok to save app data content (music/videos) on internal storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I don't know that app, I didn't tried it. But I think I can imagine about what's happening behind the scenes.

An app can save data in two places: Internal storage or external. By external storage don't think only on SD card (Android calls SD card to any external storage available). It's called external storage because it's accesible for all apps that have permissions to read the SD card. And internal storage is the allocated in system/app/data/data/(your_app_package_name). This internal storage is exclusively visible only by your app. (Except you are root user and you can edit that files).

I think that the app you mention uses internal storage, so nobody can see its contents. Also, it can encrypt those files and making them nearly impossible to read/edit by anybody who doesn't have the key.

[You can check Android Developers for consulting how to use the internal and external storage!](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Mmm, no. It's not the best idea to save music and videos in internal storage. The reason is that usually is more limited than the external. And other reason is that you can't be 100% sure that the data will remain there forever. Why? Because Android watches the internal storage more closely. Is very dependant of it and loves to have all the control. If he thinks he needs memory then maybe it can start to delete files from there, mainly the cache files (that are also saved on internal storage). Also, if the user selects your app in Apps Config and selects "Clear data" then all be erased. And all the data you save in internal counts for the total size of your app, which is not very friendly to the eyes of the user.

Ok, so you should put your big files on external storage (yes, they won't be private) but you can encrypt them and making them "invisible"!

Comment: Omg please tell me how do I 'encrypt them and making them "invisible"!'? I've been searching this on the net for weeks and tried everything. I know of making folders private with the '.' character, but it only makes them invisible to android and other versions of linux OS. I'm trying to make the files or folder invisible for any file manager or if connected to a computer. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: You can't make a file invisible at all.

Comment: It's the same. You can't. They are files and folders. You can't make them disappear! They need to be in some place. You can decide if you want to put them on internal or external storage. Those are your options.

Comment: Alright. Thank you. I'll make a separate question about encryption then.

Comment: You're welcome. Did you think about the possibility of puting those extremely secret on the cloud? In that case you'd have full control over them

Comment: The videos are on the cloud, but I would like customers to be able to download the videos. However, I would not like them to go to their computers and redistribute the content.

Comment: Nice. Encryption then